# combining IO monad with State Monad in example

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers, state-monad, io-monad

I created simple evaluator for statements. 
I would like to do it using transformers - mix IO monad with State.
Could somebody explain how to do it ?  It is something that I can't deal with it - transformers.

```
execStmt :: Stmt -> State (Map.Map String Int) ()
execStmt s = case s of
      SAssigment v e -> get >>= (\s -> put (Map.insert v (fromJust (runReader (evalExpM e) s)) s))
      SIf e s1 s2 -> get >>=  (\s -> case (fromJust (runReader (evalExpM e) s)) of
                                        0 -> execStmt s2
                                        _ -> execStmt s1
                              )
      SSkip -> return ()
      SSequence s1 s2 -> get >>= (\s -> (execStmt s1) >>= (\s' -> execStmt s2))
      SWhile e s1 -> get >>= (\s -> case (fromJust (runReader (evalExpM e) s)) of
                                        0 -> return ()
                                        _ -> (execStmt s1) >>= (\s' -> execStmt (SWhile e s1)))

execStmt' :: Stmt -> IO ()
execStmt' stmt =  putStrLn $ show $ snd $ runState (execStmt  stmt) Map.empty
```

Comment: Do you know how to do it *without* transformers? Can you make an `IO + State` monad by hand?

Comment: The way this function is written currently shows a pretty critical misunderstanding of the "monad" abstraction. before moving onto transformers, you should first try to implement your current function so as to not be partial, and potentially use monad combinators.

Comment: @HaskellFun Do you understand the State monad by itself (how to implement it)?

Comment: Yes, I can implement bind and return.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a basic program outline

```
newtype StateIO s a = SIO {runSIO :: s -> IO (a, s)}

put :: s -> StateIO s ()
put s' = SIO $ \_s -> return ((), s')

liftIO :: IO a -> StateIO s a
liftIO ia = SIO $ \s -> do
    a <- ia
    return (a, s)

instance Functor (StateIO s) where
    fmap ab (SIO sa) = SIO $ \s -> do
        (a, s') <- sa s
        let b = ab a
        return (b, s')

instance Applicative (StateIO s) where
    pure a = SIO $ \s -> return (a, s)
    (SIO sab) <*> (SIO sa) = SIO $ \s -> do
        (ab, s' ) <- sab s
        (a , s'') <- sa  s'
        let b = ab a
        return (b, s')
```

`StateIO s a` is something that takes an input state (of type `s`), and returns an IO action to produce something of type `a` as well as a new state.

To check for understanding, do the following

- Write a value of `get :: StateIO s s` which retrieves the state.
- Write an instance for `Monad (StateIO s)` (it will be similar to the code above).
- Finally, and this is the big step to understanding transformers, is to define `newtype StateT m s a = StateT {run :: s -> m (a, s)}`, and translate the above code to that (with the constraint `Monad m`). This will show you how monad transformers work.